# Mousemove relative to set element (if value is more or less)

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, user-experience

I'm currently trying to prove to myself a UI/UX concept that I came up with for a really quick way to rate and sort cards relative to each other.

However as I'm not a coder but designer my skills are limited and I'd appreciate some help with what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Here is the fiddle to look into: https://jsfiddle.net/b3dmo6L8/7/

1.) The current code is probably bad hacked-together jquery, however it brought me as far as this.

HTML

```
<div class="card">
  <span class="pos">
    <span class="num">1</span>
  </span>
  <span class="repos"></span>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.card').each(function() {
    var clicked = false;

    // follow the mouse
        $(this).on( "mousemove", function( e ) {
        if (clicked == false) {
            $('.pos', this).css('width', e.pageX);
        }
        $('.repos', this).css('width', e.pageX);
    });

    $(this).on( "mouseleave", function( e ) {
        if (clicked == false) $('.pos', this).css('width', 0);
    });

    //…
```

2.) My goal now would be to have prototype that does the following:

a.) On the first click on any of the cards, the clicked card will get position number 1 and is set. You can see that with the indicator. The number is always just visible on hover.

[image]

b.) However when one card is set, all other positiones of other cards should be **relative** based on the first initial position of the first clicked card.

[image]

**And that shuold of course not only work for the numbers 1 and 2 but it should be possible to simply rank them by numbers, the further the click to the right of the card is.**

c.) I also included a 2nd indicator once a card got clicked that would allow for a "reposition" of the set indicator. In case you've set the initial click to far to the right.

Here is the fiddle to look into: https://jsfiddle.net/b3dmo6L8/7/

How could I achieve the correct number output and the repositioning of an indicator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive this is what you are after. The main change i made was your on click function. I added a global cardCount and made it so that if the card hasnt been clicked it sets the number of the card and increments the global variable. If the widths need to be compares in the opposite direction just change the `<` to `>`

```
if(clicked){
    //$('.pos', this).css('width', e.pageX);
}else{
    window.cardCount++;
    $('.num', this).text(window.cardCount);
}
```

Then to make the counts update depends on widths of other clicks, i added a double loop to go through the widths compare them and see what the new calculated position of the card is like so:

```
$('.card').each(function() {
  var width = $('.pos', this).width();
  var newPos = 1;
  $('.card').each(function() {
    if($('.pos', this).width() > 0){
      if($('.pos', this).width() < width){
        newPos++;
      }
    }
  });
  $('.num', this).text( newPos);
});
```

I think this solution is suitable for your question.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 window.cardCount = 0;
 // Clone card 5 times
  var $card = $(".card");
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      $card.clone().appendTo('#wrap');
  }

 // For each card
 $('.card').each(function() {
    var clicked = false;
    var card = this;
    $('.cancel', this).on('click', function(e){
          window.cardCount--;
          $('.pos', card).css('width', e.pageX);
          $('.repos', card).css('width', 0);
          clicked = false;
          e.stopPropagation();
    });
    
    // follow the mouse
  $(this).on( "mousemove", function( e ) {
        if (clicked == false) {
         $('.pos', this).css('width', e.pageX);
        }else{
          $('.repos', this).css('width', e.pageX);
        }
        
        $('.card').each(function() {
          var width = $('.pos', this).width();
          var newPos = 1;
          $('.card').each(function() {
            if($('.pos', this).width() > 0){
              if($('.pos', this).width() > width){
                newPos++;
              }
            }
          });
          $('.num', this).text( newPos);
        });
    });
    
    $(this).on( "mouseleave", function( e ) {
        if (clicked == false) $('.pos', this).css('width', 0);
    });
    
    $(this).on( "click", function(e) {
        if(clicked){
     $('.pos', this).css('width', e.pageX);
        }else{
          window.cardCount++;
         $('.num', this).text(window.cardCount);
        }
        
        clicked = true;
        $('.repos', this).css({
         'display':'inline-block',
          'width': 0,
          });
          
        $('.card').each(function() {
          var width = $('.pos', this).width();
          var newPos = 1;
          $('.card').each(function() {
            if($('.pos', this).width() > 0){
              if($('.pos', this).width() > width){
                newPos++;
              }
            }
          });
          $('.num', this).text( newPos);
        });
    });
    
    $(this).hover(
      function() {
        $('.num', this).fadeIn(50);
      }, function() {
        $('.num', this).fadeOut(50);
      }
  );
    
  });
});
```

```css
#wrap { margin: 50px auto; width: 100%; }

.card {
  width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.pos, .repos {
  height: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  border-right: 2px solid #007ED7;
  background: rgba(0, 126, 215, .1);
  -webkit-transition: width .1s; /* Safari */
  transition: width .1s;
}

.pos, .repos { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
}

.pos { z-index: 2; }
.repos { 
  display: none; 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1); 
  z-index: 1; 
}

.num { 
  font-family: sans-serif; 
  display: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #007ED7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">

<div class="card">
  <span class="pos">
    <span class="num"></span>
    <span class="cancel">x</span>
  </span>
  <span class="repos"></span>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Exactly. Thanks so much. Do you have any idea how the 2nd click on a card could reset the position? How this could be made? Imagine the first click was too far right, then I can't set a new position one – in that case I want to "reposition" the first click on the card again to go further left … you know what I mean?

Comment: @matt see amended answer :)

Comment: awesome :) great.

Comment: @matt can you mark this as the answer than if it worked? thanks

Comment: and one last question I have though: Is it also possible to completely cancel a set-position? e.g. I clicked into a card, and then want to revert the click. I'm thinking of `<span class="cancel">✖</span>` that is moving along with each blue indicator-line but is invisible, until my cursor matches the same "already-clicked" position again, if I then click the x, the previous made click is set back.

Comment: @matt see amended solution, you will have to style it yourself and trigger when its visible

Comment: Thank you. I'll style that right away. Two more small things I can't find the proper solution yet. 1.) the 2nd indicator once a card is clicked should only be visible if the hover is above the card - otherwise two indicators and bars will above a card. 2.) the 2nd indicator should also show the number and count in order to know if the repositioning changes the value relative to another entry. Any last ideas on that? That would be awesome, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @matt im not 100% sure what you mean

Comment: Hey @Deckerz … I'm referring to this. Imagine you clicked into a card, the 2nd indicator also appears to "reposition" the 1st indicator within the same card: https://imgur.com/9o4b7Kn This 2nd indicator shuold only show up on hover on the card and not stay if clicked into the card once as it does now. Also the 2nd indicator should probably also show the number: https://imgur.com/2POQp8v

Comment: As much as i would like to help, i think this is becoming a little too out of scope for the question. I shouldnt require too much rejigging of the code i have provided you. Sorry!

Comment: Hey, not to worry, thank you, I guess I can figure that out myself as you say. One last thing though that might be a little difficult for me. I actually didn't realise that I asked for a different "count/num" of the cards up top. See my post up top. Actually if one card is clicked and the next card is hovered "right" of the first indicator it should still be 1 as it is "further right" as the first indicator on the other card.

Comment: @matt see ammendment